# Specify argument name and type via variables in fastapi

Tags: python, dynamic, swagger, arguments, fastapi

I would like to do the following:

```
from fastapi import Body, FastAPI

app = FastAPI()


@app.put("/blubb")
def f(b: str):
    return f_imported(b)
```

But I want the set the argument name `b` and the argument type `str` via variables.
The reason is that i want to call an imported function `f_imported` and would like the naming convention and type annotation used there to be respected in the swagger docs.
Is there a way to dynamically insert argument name and type to the definition of `f`?

I know that i can get the argument names and annotations from `f_imported` via `inspect.getfullargspec` and I know how to dynamically set the type:

```
fas = inspect.getfullargspec(f_imported)
arg_name = fas.args[1]
arg_type = fas.annotations[arg_name]

@app.put("/blubb")

def f(b: arg_type):
    return f_imported(b)
```

To dynamically set the name the only idea i have is to use eval or exec which i would rather not do.